# Mutliplicative Group of Congruences Classes Calculation

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to show the congruence classes $\overline{2^{n-1}+1}$ and $\overline{2^{n-1}-1}$ have over two, elements in $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n \mathbb{Z})^\times$. However, I am being a knucklehead. The order of our group is $2^{n-1}$, so I believe that $\overline{2^n} = \overline{0}$. Therefore,

$\overline{(2^{n-1}+1)(2^{n-1}+1)} = \overline{2^{2n-2} + 2^n + 1}$

$= \overline{2^{2n-2}} +\overline{2^n} + \overline{1}$

$= \overline{2^{2n-2}} + \overline{1}$

Supposedly this element has order two, and so should equal $\overline{1}$ but I cannot see why $\overline{2^{2n-2}}=\overline{0}$ is true; it seems that it should be $\overline{2^{2n-2}} = \overline{1}$, which is not what I want.

So, is this really an element of order two? If not, I could use some help finding one.

**EDIT:**

Perhaps I have it backwards. Perhaps $\overline{2^{n-1}} = \overline{0}$, and since $\overline{2^n} = \overline{2 \cdot 2^{n-1}}$, we can say this is zero because $2 \cdot 2^{n-1}$ is a multiple of $2^{n-1}$ whose congruence class is zero.

Does this seem right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement you're trying to prove is only true if $n\geq 2$, so let's assume that.  To say that $\overline{2^{2n-2}}=\overline{0}$ just means that $2^{2n-2}$ is a multiple of $2^n$, which is true because $2n-2\geq n$ (since $n\geq 2$).  It's not clear to me why you think that $\overline{2^{2n-2}}$ would be $\overline{1}$.  Maybe you are trying to think inside the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n \mathbb{Z})^\times$, but note that $\overline{2}$ is not even an element of that group.

Comment: Oh wait! $2^{2n-2} = 2^{2(n-1)} = 2^2 2^n 2^{-1} = 2 \cdot 2^n$, which is why $\overline{2^{2n-2}} = \overline{0}$, right?

Comment: Not quite: $2^{2(n-1)}\neq 2^22^n2^{-1}$.  Rather, $2^{2n-2}=2^{n+n-2}=2^n\cdot 2^{n-2}$.